# Laravel 4 Upload Image to server

Tags: php, image, laravel

I'm trying to upload images to laravel and I'm having some trouble :S

My view:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{url('admin/test')}}" id="formm" >
        <input  type="file" placeholder="browse" id="imagen_item" name="imagen_item" accept="image/*"/>
        <input type="submit" style="font-size: 20px" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

My routes.php

```
Route::post('admin/test','AdminController@test');
```

My Controller

```
public function test()
{
    $file = Input::file('imagen_item');
    var_dump($file);
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
    if(is_object($file))
    {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload_success = Input::file('imagen')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        if( $upload_success ) {
            echo 'save this url: '.$filename." in the DB";
        }
    }
}
```

And what I get after submitting the form:

```
null
A
A.A
```

So obvously the problem is the I'm not thetting the image from the input form.. but why?? I have the same name... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! 
I changed the form tag for:

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/rnew_item', 'files' => true,'id'=>'formm')) }}
```

and ofc the  for:

```
    {{ Form::close() }}
```